# yeoman generator blocked by Lodash

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I wanted to add  new directive to my test project and I got error message;
When I run yo mean-seed I get : "*(!) generator#hookFor() is deprecated. Use generator#composeWith() - see http://yeoman.io/authoring/composability.html*";

Then when I select sub generator ng-directive,'name','less',1 i get

```
(!) #_ is deprecated. Require your own version of Lodash or underscore.string
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.js:579
    throw e;
          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'capitalize' of undefined
```

How can I change/update it to generate?

my versions are:

```
npm --version && node --version
2.9.0
v0.12.2
```

Answer (score 0):

`generator-mean-seed` doesn't tag versions of his dependency, so the generator just break after a non-backward compatible update.

I opened an issue on his generator: https://github.com/notorii/generator-mean-seed/issues/19

Comment: so , how should I update my set up to have it running?

Comment: There's no way unless the generator author fix it.

Comment: Well actually, I sent a pull request to the generator, so you can install from my git branch until it's merged and it'll work if there's no further bugs https://github.com/notorii/generator-mean-seed/pull/20

Comment: I could not install it; probably I did something wrong; I will wait until you merge it; thank you